ASP.NET Core project stopped working after I added areas
I'm following along an ASP.NET Core tutorial. When I added areas into the project, it stopped working. HomeController.cs and CategoryController.cs were in the main project's Controllers folder. I moved them to their respective area's Controllers folders. I added [Area("Admin")] and [Area("Customer")] on top of the HomeController and CategoryController classes.
When I try debugging the website, I get an 404 error:

Couldn't find the website for https://localhost:7010/

Can anyone help me with that? Let me know if you require the contents of some other files. Thanks in advance!
Program.cs file: 
Solution Explorer: 
I tried adding this in the Program.cs:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
          endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name : "areas",
            pattern : "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
          );
       });

I tried removing area:exists in Program.cs. I also tried to move the controller files back to the original Controllers folder.

I solved the problem. It appears that I should've written what area should be revoked instead of {area:exists} at:
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Instead it should be like this:
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

